# Snowflake cumulative sum for multiple entry in same date for a given partition

Tags: snowflake-cloud-data-platform, window-functions, cumulative-sum

I have a table with below data set. I want to get the cumulative sum based on PK1 and PK2 as on TXN_DATE. I have tried with cumulative window frame functions and its giving the expected result. But I want the output to be in desired format which needs to be grouped by TXN_DATE.

[image: Table values]

```
SELECT
    PK1
    ,PK2
    ,TXN_DATE
    ,QTY
    ,SUM(QTY) OVER (PARTITION BY PK1,PK2 ORDER BY TXN_DATE ROWS BETWEEN UNBOUNDED PRECEDING AND CURRENT ROW) SUM_QTY 
FROM MY_TABLE 
ORDER BY TXN_DATE;
```

Above query is giving the result as below,

[image: Current Result of above query]

I want the result as shown below in either one of the format, Can someone help to get the desired result based on this.

[image: Required Result]

OR

[image: Required Result 1]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just get rid of `rows between unbounded preceding and current row` in your window function. The sum() window function will make the daily total the same for all rows on the same day that way.

```
with SOURCE_DATA as
(
select   COLUMN1::string as PK1
        ,COLUMN2::string as PK2
        ,COLUMN3::date   as TXN_DATE
        ,COLUMN4::int    as QTY
from (values 
('P001', 'XYZ', '2022-11-03', 15),
('P001', 'XYZ', '2022-11-08', -1),
('P001', 'XYZ', '2022-11-12', -4),
('P002', 'ABZ', '2022-11-03', 10),
('P002', 'ABZ', '2022-11-03', 1),       -- This was listed as ABC in the photo
('P002', 'ABZ', '2022-11-05', -5),
('P002', 'ABZ', '2022-11-10', -1),
('P002', 'ABZ', '2022-11-10', -1),
('P002', 'ABZ', '2022-11-10', 1)
     )
)
select   *
        ,sum(QTY) over (partition by PK1, PK2 order by TXN_DATE) QUANTITY
from SOURCE_DATA
order by PK1, TXN_DATE
;
```

Output:

| PK1 | PK2 | TXN_DATE | QTY | QUANTITY |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| P001 | XYZ | 2022-11-03 | 15 | 15 |
| P001 | XYZ | 2022-11-08 | -1 | 14 |
| P001 | XYZ | 2022-11-12 | -4 | 10 |
| P002 | ABZ | 2022-11-03 | 10 | 11 |
| P002 | ABZ | 2022-11-03 | 1 | 11 |
| P002 | ABZ | 2022-11-05 | -5 | 6 |
| P002 | ABZ | 2022-11-10 | -1 | 5 |
| P002 | ABZ | 2022-11-10 | -1 | 5 |
| P002 | ABZ | 2022-11-10 | 1 | 5 |

Comment: Thanks @Greg Pavlik... My bad was not exploring on this. Thanks for pointing out... Got the desired output